# App seems like launching more than once in landscape mode after splash screen?

Tags: java, android

I have a splash screen and after that my main activity starts. This **works fine in portrait mode** but if in case i tilt my phone in **landscape mode**, the **main activity can be seen launching more than once after splash screen**.

I tried using android:launchMode="singleInstance" but in that case i am not able to attach files in feedback alert-box.

Following is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.tel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;
    TextView toolbar_title_mainActivity, main_textView, disclaimer_txtView;
    CardView SearchDept, SearchName, disclaimer, feedback;
    ImageView back;
    ArrayList<Uri> arrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    ArrayAdapter<Uri> myFileListAdapter;
    ListView listViewFiles;
    Dialog alertDialog;

    final int RQS_LOADIMAGE = 0;
    final int RQS_SENDEMAIL = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_main_activity);
        toolbar_title_mainActivity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        main_textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textView);
        main_textView.setPaintFlags(main_textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar_title_mainActivity.setText("Hry. Govt. Telephone Directory");
        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        disclaimer = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.disclaimer);
        feedback = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);

        SearchDept = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView1_mainActivity);
        SearchName = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView2_mainActivity);
        SearchDept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CardViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        SearchName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ByNameListActivity.class);
                startActivity(j);
            }
        });

        disclaimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.disclaimer);
                alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        feedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 alertDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.feedback);
                alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                ImageView send_btn=(ImageView)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.send);
                ImageView attach_btn=(ImageView)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.attachment);
                final TextView to_email_add=(TextView)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.email_address);
                to_email_add.setText("tel@gmail.com");
                final EditText email_subject=(EditText)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.email_subject);
                final EditText email_text=(EditText)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.email_text);
                final EditText mobile_no=(EditText)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.mobile_text);

                email_subject.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (!hasFocus) {
                            hideKeyboard(v);
                        }
                    }
                });

                email_text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (!hasFocus) {
                            hideKeyboard(v);
                        }
                    }
                });

                myFileListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Uri>(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        arrayUri);
                listViewFiles = (ListView)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.filelist);
                listViewFiles.setAdapter(myFileListAdapter);

                listViewFiles.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        myFileListAdapter.remove(arrayUri.get(position));
                        myFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "You unattached one item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });



                attach_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_LOADIMAGE);

                    }
                });


                send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String email_add=to_email_add.getText().toString();
                        String email_sub=email_subject.getText().toString();
                        String email_txt=email_text.getText().toString();
                        String emailAddressList[] = {email_add};
                        String mobileNo=mobile_no.getText().toString();
                        String info=email_txt+"\n\nPhone Number :"+mobileNo;


                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddressList);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, email_sub);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,info);

                        if(arrayUri.isEmpty()&& isValidPhone(mobileNo)&& !(mobileNo.isEmpty())){
                            //send email without photo attached
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.setType("plain/text");

                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }, 5000);

                        }else if(arrayUri.size() == 1 && isValidPhone(mobileNo)&& !(mobileNo.isEmpty())){
                            //send email with ONE photo attached
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayUri.get(0));
                            intent.setType("image/*");

                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }, 5000);

                        }else if(arrayUri.size()>1&& isValidPhone(mobileNo)&& !(mobileNo.isEmpty())){
                            //send email with MULTI photo attached
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayUri);
                            intent.setType("image/*");

                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }, 5000);

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Phone number is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please provide valid details"));

                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch(requestCode){
                case RQS_LOADIMAGE:
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    arrayUri.add(imageUri);
                    myFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case RQS_SENDEMAIL:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValidPhone(String phone)
    {
        String expression = "^([0-9\\+]|\\(\\d{1,3}\\))[0-9\\-\\. ]{3,15}$";
        CharSequence inputString = phone;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
        if (matcher.matches())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        int orientation;
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            // or = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        }else {
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
        }
        // Add code if needed
//        listViewFiles.setAdapter(myFileListAdapter);
//        myFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="14"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.tel.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_main_activity"
        layout="@layout/toolbar">
    </include>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="How would you like to search?"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#1A237E"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchby_btns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView1_mainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#e97c1d">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search By Department.."
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2_mainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardView1_mainActivity"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#e97c1d">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search By Name.."
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="8.5">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/hry_map"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/map_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/disclaimer"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#424242">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Disclaimer"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/feedback"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/disclaimer"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#424242">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Feedback"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SplashScreenActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.telephonedirectory;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//    private GifImageView gifimageview;
    private ProgressBar progressBarSplashScreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        }

//        gifimageview=(GifImageView)findViewById(R.id.gifSplashscreenImage);
        progressBarSplashScreen=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbarSplashscreen);
        progressBarSplashScreen.setVisibility(progressBarSplashScreen.VISIBLE);

        //set GifImageView Resource

        /*try {
            InputStream inputStream=getAssets().open("splash_Screen.png");
            byte[] bytes= IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            gifimageview.setBytes(bytes);
            gifimageview.startAnimation();
        }catch (IOException ex){

        }*/

        //Wait for 4 seconds and start activity main
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
            }
        },2000);
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        int orientation;
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            // or = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        }else {
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
        }
        // Add code if needed
//        listViewFiles.setAdapter(myFileListAdapter);
//        myFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you finish splashActivity, when you start MainActivity?

Comment: @Nitin Patel :You can see the splash screen code above as i have added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Launch mode you should use `"singleTask"` for this .

Because `singleInstance` creates separate task stack for Activity and do not check activity in current Task Stack.

while `"singleTask"` check each time if an Activity exist in Task Stack it can not create new one.

Comment: Okay! Thanks @Chetan Joshi. one more question plzzz: if i click outside the dialog it dismisses but the attachments that i attached in feedback alert box before touching outside can still be seen if i open the dialog again?

Comment: Attachment means you have take path of attachment then you should  add that path in Activity bundle while adding and when you open dialog again first check any attachment is there in Bundle or not .

Comment: i am attaching those attachments from gallery of phone. You can check my code for this above.

Comment: same you are trying to add URI so when you select any URI keep it in Android Activity Bundle so if any case your dialog is dismissed then you can get it form Activity bundle for that instance.